# Is it possible to restore answers on your question that have been edited?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers

I recently asked [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/67685/is-it-possible-to-develop-web-based-games-using-corona-sdk/67686#67686), I didn't accept the answer because I usually like to leave my questions open for a while before accepting to encourage more users to answer.

**Alex M.** answered my question and added that if i want to develop 2d web based games, it's better to use **x** engine and **y**.

Today I came back to the question, to take a look at the engines he recommended, but found that **Byte56** have edited it, deleting the part I'm interested in.

So is there an option allowing the asker to refuse edits on the answers, or restore information removed by editors?

Comment: @MartijnPieters it is ok, i'll leave it as is, i just wanted to see the engines and now i bookmarked them, could you please tell me how to see the revisions? i know how to see them if someone has edited my answer because i receive notifications but how to see the original answer? how did you get that link?

Comment: You can click on the 'edited ... ago' link above Byte56's name.

Comment: P.s. you're welcome to post here, but you realize each site in the network has its own Meta as well? (just checking)

Comment: @Bart i know that each site has its own meta and i have participated in many metas, but i asked here because i wanted to know if this feature is available on stackexchange in general, i wasn't asking about gamedev.se in particular

Comment: Okay, good. :) Wasn't entirely sure, and part of it (the motivation behind the edit) seemed to be better suited on the Gamedev SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A diamond moderator edited that post because the tech recommendations in it were attracting spam answers (probably now deleted).

See the [post revision history](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/67686/revisions).

The post owner can always roll back an edit like this and you can make the same rollback as a suggested edit, but I would not suggest you do so here. You can still access the information in the revision history (found via the 'edited ... ago' link above the editor's name).

You could ask Byte56 for a clarification, if you wanted to, by using `@byte56` in a comment below that answer.